# tensorflow dbg error: Encode method is not implemented for DatasetVariantWrapper objects

Tags: debugging, tensorflow

I'm new to debugging a Tensorflow code. 
Following the [instruction](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger), I installed `pyreadline` and ran my Tensorflow code with `--debug` option.

```
tfdbg> run -f has_inf_or_nan
2017-11-30 13:26:04.471758: E C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\tf-nightly-windows\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\kernels\dataset.cc:58] The Encode()
method is not implemented for DatasetVariantWrapper objects.
2017-11-30 13:26:04.601759: E C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\tf-nightly-windows\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\kernels\dataset.cc:58] The Encode()
method is not implemented for DatasetVariantWrapper objects.
2017-11-30 13:26:04.662760: E C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\tf-nightly-windows\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\kernels\dataset.cc:58] The Encode()
method is not implemented for DatasetVariantWrapper objects.
2017-11-30 13:26:04.787768: E C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\tf-nightly-windows\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\kernels\dataset.cc:58] The Encode()
method is not implemented for DatasetVariantWrapper objects.
2017-11-30 13:26:05.208772: E C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\tf-nightly-windows\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\kernels\dataset.cc:58] The Encode()
method is not implemented for DatasetVariantWrapper objects.

Epoch: 0

2017-11-30 13:26:08.967878: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\tf-nightly-windows\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\debug\debug_graph_utils.cc:240] For
debugging, tfdbg has set the parallel_iterations attribute of all scheduled Enter/RefEnter nodes to 1. (This does not affect subsequent non-debug run
.)
2017-11-30 13:26:12.485000: F C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\tf-nightly-windows\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\debug\debug_io_utils.cc:623] Non-OK
status: env->NewWritableFile(file_path, &f) status: Not found: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile: L:\SysTemp\AppData\Local\Temp\tfdbg_60jn0oyn/_tfd
g_device_,job_localhost,replica_0,task_0,device_GPU_0/Training/gradients/BiLSTM/BiLSTM/fw/fw/while/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/lstm_cell/mul_2_grad/Broa
castGradientArgs/f_acc/max_size_0_DebugIdentity_1512073572475000 : The system cannot find the path specified.
; No such process
```

Then the execution stopped and returned to the windows command Prompt. My Tensorflow version is 1.5.0-dev20171120 (python 3.5). I'm using `Dataset` API to read data into the model.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the file path is too long, Windows limits **max path length**, try

```
sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess, dump_root='L:\debug_tmp')
```